# Distance between two lines (textbook answer vs practical application)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming, and Computer Graphics" as a refresher, and leading in to some more complex real world problems down the line. However, one of the early chapters has a bit of math that seems overly complicated. This question deals with a problem from the textbook, that I believe the solution is far simpler than their recommended one.

The problem is to find the distance between two lines (in 2 or 3 dimensions).

Some set up:

1) Lines are set up parametrically.

Line 1: [image: P_{1}(t_{1})]

Line 2: [image: P_{2}(t_{2})]

Where P = S + tV -- S is the starting point (say, A) and equals (1-t) * A

---

Now the book states to use this solution : [image: ||P_{1}-P_{2}|| ^2]

Expanded looks like:

[image: d = f( t_{1}, t_{2} ) = P_{1}(t_{1})^2 + P_{2}(t_{2})^2 - 2P_{1}\cdot P_{2}(t_{2})]

Then the books next step is to expand this, and take the derivatives with respect to time for both

[image: t_{1}] and [image: t_{2}]

Once the derivatives have been calculated. We move to a matrix form, and solve using some linear algebra.

---

My question is this, why would I use that series of steps when I already know the [ x, y, z ] for both points using the parametric. With those values wouldn't the simpler solution be just to do:

[image: V_{a} = S_{1} + tV_{1}]

[image: V_{b} = S_{2} + tV]

Where both a and b are vectors.

Then:

[image: V = V_{b} - V_{a}]

Finally:

[image: \sqrt{V\cdot V}]

Is there some direct application of the former equations that I am missing (the book does not elaborate currently on its applications here)? I've had some discussion with other game developers, and we haven't found much a use case for the linear algebra set up.

---

Edit: (The linear algebra solution)

First both derivatives with respect to time:

[image: df/dt1]

[image: df/dt2]

Then in matrix form, solve for both t variables (factor of 2 removed):

[image: Final matrix form]

Comment: Your method would not work, since you don't know what $t_1, t_2$ are. When you do subtraction, you get a distance function that depends on two variables. It gives you the distance between any two points from both of the lines. Your goal is to find the minimum value of this two-variable function. That's why the derivative and the equations to solve.

Comment: I see. However, since this problem comes from a real world game application, both variables are always known. In which case is the dot/root method not the correct way to manage that scenario?

Comment: Do you mean you know where the distance is the shortest? If that's the case, of course you can use your method. The method in the book indicates the way to find the distance if you only know **some** point on each line and their direction (in other words, the equation of the lines).

Comment: That is correct. Thanks for your reply, this lines up with what others are saying. No pun intended.

Answer (score 2):

There is some intuition behind the solution: the closest points $P_i$ are such that the vector $P_1P_2$ is perpendicular to both directions of these lines. So
$$\langle (S_1 + t_1 V_1) - (S_2 + t_2 V_2), V_1 \rangle = 0\\ 
\langle (S_1 + t_1 V_1) - (S_2 + t_2 V_2), V_2 \rangle = 0 $$

You get a system of two equations with $2$ unknowns $t_1$, $t_2$ which is uniquely solvable if the direction vectors $V_i$ of the lines are not proportionals. Get $t_1$, $t_2$ and so the closest points $P_1$ and $P_2$.